# Not able to locate element in anchor (haref) tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In menu there is option "Feedback" and i want to click on that element using selenium webdriver but unfortunatly i am not able to locate that element using `xpath`, `css`, `linktext`, `partial link text`, `id`.

please check for element below:

```
<a href="javascript:openFeedbackModal();">Feedback</a>
```

please suggest me how to locate that element.

Comment: Try xpath("//*[text()='feedback']")). let us know.

Comment: JavascriptExectuor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; js.executeScript("your js code to select element");

Comment: find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, "javascript")]"[text() = "feedback")]"). It reads, find an element that has a "href" attribute that contains "javascript" string and has a text attribute that has exactly this string, "Feedback". Hope it helps.